# Якорная ссылка с прокруткой на jQuery с другой страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вопрос возник, использую данную js функцию, на index странице работает на ура.
Нужно, с других страниц по клику в меню(главная, прайс и т.п.), перейти на index и выполнить данный скроллинг, смотря по какой ссылке кликнули. 
Вот не знаю, можно ли эту функцию сделать универсальной или нужно писать другую?
И еще вопрос как избавиться от навязчивых #price, я бы эти ссылки вообще хотел сделать без index.html, а сразу на домен и чтоб хеш не писал в адресе, не красиво, конечно это только главная страница так.
В IE прокрутка не работает к сожалению.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top -70; //-70px это у меня приклеиное меню, если подскажите как якоря сдлеать -70px, буду признателен
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">Заголовок 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Заголовок 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Заголовок 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h3 id="1">Заголовок 1</h3>
  <p>тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля </p>
  <h3 id="2" style="margin-top: 200px;">Заголовок 2</h3>
  <p>тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля </p>
  <h3 id="3" style="margin-top: 200px;">Заголовок 3</h3>
  <p>тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля тра-ля-ля-ля-ля </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body,html').scrollTop(0);
    $("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top -70; //-70px это у меня приклеиное меню, если подскажите как якоря сдлеать -70px, буду признателен
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
    var hash = location.hash;
    if($(hash).length){
        var top = $(hash).offset().top -70;
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    }
});
```

По поводу хештега.
Можно избавиться. Xеш тег хранить не в ссылке, а в аттрибуте, например data-hash="#price1". Хеш тег читать, писать в cookie, localStorage, sessionStorage (на выбор). При переходе читать и сразу стирать. Выполнить действие, если хеш тег можно применить к странице.

Comment: однако работает, спасибо большое, по поводу хеша к сожалению не понял, про писать стирать. Не силён.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот скрипт который без хешей в адресной строке мотает, можно его поправить, что бы еще и с других страниц работал?

```
$('a[href^="#"]').bind("click", function(e){
var anchor = $(this);
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top -70
}, 1000);

e.preventDefault();
```

});